# Git gui с хорошим поиском по коду во всех ветках?

Tags: ubuntu, git

Есть ли удобные git gui инструменты в которых внедрен поиск по коду во всех ветках? то есть удобная замена git grep.
Для ubuntu/

Comment: ИМХО - Если вы правильно подписываете коммиты, то вам не нужно искать ничего в коде. Ну а вообще для ваших целей наверно лучше смотреть в сторону IDE с поддержкой GIT, вроде VSCode или Atom, а не просто GIT-GUI.

Comment: если git grep не устраивает - напишите свой поисковичек. делов то.